# How to retrieve all elements between two nodes with a given class name in XPATH

Tags: javascript, python, html, xpath

I extracted this code from tradingview, I want to get access to all the div elements using xpath between this two elements namely C1 indicator and C2 indicator:
[image]

I tried the following but does not seems working. Any thoughts?

```
*[following-sibling::div[contains(@data-section-name,'C1 Indicator')] and preceding-sibling::div[contains(@data-section-name,'C2 Indicator')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point you missed here is that `div` elements containing the `data-section-name` attribute are not siblings, they are each inside another parent `div` elements with `titleWrap` class name.  So, I guess you should search for siblings of those `titleWrap` divs, while these parent divs should be located by their child divs containing `data-section-name` attributes. Something like the following:

```py
*[following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'titleWrap') and .//div[contains(@data-section-name,'C1 Indicator')]] and preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class,'titleWrap') and .//div[contains(@data-section-name,'C2 Indicator')]]
```

Comment: I understand your logic and syntax but I tried but does not come out with any results.. im trying to figuring out why and what is missing

Comment: I solved: //*[preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class,'titleWrap') and .//div[contains(@data-section-name,'C1 Indicator')]] and following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'titleWrap') and .//div[contains(@data-section-name,'C2 Indicator')]]]